# Not able to install data-hub-export-bundle in pimcore

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-datahub

I'm trying to install data-hub-export-bundle but it's showing this error.

```
Could not find a matching version of package pimcore/data-hub-file-export. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which ma tches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

[image: Composer error]

Process Manager and Data Hub are both enabled and installed as per the [Pimcore documentation](https://pimcore.com/docs/data-hub-file-export/current/Installation/index.html).

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "sort-packages": true,
        "process-timeout": 0
    },
    "require": {
        "basilicom/pimcore-data-quality-bundle": "^2.2",
        "ci-hub/simple-rest-adapter-bundle": "^2.0",
        "elements/process-manager-bundle": "^4.0",
        "pimcore/customer-management-framework-bundle": "^3.3",
        "pimcore/data-hub": "^1.5",
        "pimcore/data-importer": "^1.7",
        "pimcore/pimcore": "^10.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.1.12"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "pimcore/data-hub": "Universal data interface for GraphQL, CSV and other formats"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Pimcore\\Model\\DataObject\\": "var/classes/DataObject"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": "Pimcore\\Composer::postCreateProject",
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Pimcore\\Composer::postInstall",
            "@pimcore-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Pimcore\\Composer::postUpdate",
            "@pimcore-scripts",
            "Pimcore\\Composer::executeMigrationsUp",
            "@pimcore-scripts"
        ],
        "pimcore-scripts": [
            "Pimcore\\Composer::clearCache",
            "Pimcore\\Composer::installAssets"
        ],
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share composer.json contents? Also, there is no pimcore/data-hub-file-export package on packagist.org

Comment: Here's the file of my composer.json @s3c => https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEOUibOd3nLuenweONNyDKYl14W1Mod-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Links tend to die out. Please copy the contents of the composer.json directly into the question using triple backtick ( \`\`\` ) syntax before and after the code.

Comment: heyy! I have attached the picture above named composer.json as it was not getting aligned after pasting. can you pleaase check now

Comment: Hey, I edited your question, and I welcome you to try to edit it yourself (wait until the edit is approved) and learn from it on how to do it properly yourself. That said, I have the same issue with `pimcore/data-hub-file-export` and I've already asked for a solution on Pimcore, but I've yet to receive any response. The fact of the matter is, that the package stated we should use in the documentation simply does not exist on packagist.org.

Answer (score 2):

We are experiencing the same issue.

The problem is caused by [Pimcore Datahub File Export](https://pimcore.com/docs/data-hub-file-export/current/index.html) being an `ENTERPRISE`-only module. You can tell by the badge on its page. It's not available for the "community" edition of Pimcore.

Answer (score 0):

DataHub exporter is a paid module.
If you dislike the idea to pay, feel free to
create an own **CLI command** https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Development_Tools_and_Details/Console_CLI.html

You can execute it regularly using **MaintenanceTask**
https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Maintenance_Tasks.html

You can find Maintenance tasks samples in /vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Maintenance/Tasks/*Task.php
https://talk.pimcore.org/t/pimcore-maintenance-task-set-interval/4145

Files export is easily done using **FlySystem**
https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.2/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/File_Storage_Setup.html

Including FTP:
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle/blob/3.x/docs/3-interacting-with-ftp-and-sftp-servers.md